# Can't access the backend of my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

Tried to log in to my wordpress site today, and wp-admin showed up as a blank white screen. I tried removing the theme (no change, so I added it back), removing plugins(again no change, so I added them back), and doing a fresh wordpress install. Now, the front end works, but when I try to access the backend it says: 
"No Data Received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"
I'm using Chrome, but I also tried it in Firefox and it says, "The connection has timed out." Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

did you try clearing your cache and cookies?

is this a shared hosting or dedicated hosting? If you get these errors with a fresh install, default theme and no plugins, on a shared hosting, I'd ask the hosting company because it is not normal ...

Comment: Cleared my cache every time I tried something new, and it's dedicated hosting through Godaddy.

Comment: by fresh install you mean deleting the whole database and all files, then uploading + installing fresh again? no custom htaccess / php.ini settings?

This would mean your host can't handle Wordpress. I am pretty sure that Godaddy does... however, you may contact them even if they will first reply with a dumb reminder, you may have to insist a bit on that.